# How do I enter a "Key" symbol in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am trying to create a drawing on draw.io describing the database architecture for a project but am unable to find the "KEY" symbol.

Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Search for "key" in the images library section

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the key as text (for example, when denoting parent keys, foreign keys, etc) within an object you can use the key character within unicode: . I have not found a web-browser that does not render it.

I usually just copy-paste any symbols I need from either the character map (font=Helvetica) or from the web.

[fileformat.info page for unicode character 'KEY'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f511/index.htm)